# Update multiple rows with known keys without inserting new rows if nonexistent keys are found

Tags: mysql, insert

Let's imagine that we have table **items**...

```
table: items
item_id INT PRIMARY AUTO_INCREMENT
title VARCHAR(255)
views INT
```

Let's imagine that it is filled with something like

```
(1, item-1, 10),
(2, item-2, 10),
(3, item-3, 15)
```

I want to make **multi** update view for this items from data taken from this array [item_id] => [views]

```
'1' => '50',
'2' => '60',
'3' => '70',
'5' => '10'
```

IMPORTANT! Please note that we have item_id=5 in array, but we don't have item_id=5 in database.

I can use **INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**, but this way image_id=5 will be inserted into talbe items. How to avoid inserting new key? I just want item_id=5 be skipped because it is not in table.

Of course, before execution I can select existing keys from items table; then compare with keys in array; delete nonexistent keys and perform **INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**. But maybe there is some more elegant solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't simply issue multiple update statements? That would be way cleaner (if perhaps not as efficient) than going through `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: As far as I know it isn't possible to UPDATE multiple rows in one query (in MySQl at least). I'm looking for such "hack" because the number of updated rows is about 60K and constantly growing. That's why I don't like to generate 60K update statements - it will take too long to execute such chain of queries.

Comment: Have you tried using prepared statements with your language's variant of `execute_many()`. That way the overhead of constructing and parsing the query is eliminated.

Comment: Please, could you tell mу what is execute_many()? I've tried to google, but failed. I'm using PHP.

Comment: Unfortunately the standard PHP implementation of the MySQL API lacks prepared statement capabilities, but MySQLi does support it. It lacks a native `execute_many()` function, but you can create a prepared statement using `mysqli_stmt::prepare()`, then use `mysqli_stmt::bind_param()` and `mysqli_stmt::execute()` for each row in a loop to specify different data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try to generate a table of literals and update items by joining with the table:

```
UPDATE items
    JOIN (SELECT 1 as item_id, 50 as views
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 2 as item_id, 60 as views
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 3 as item_id, 70 as views
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 5 as item_id, 10 as views
          ) as updates
         USING(item_id)
 SET items.views = updates.views;
```

Comment: Very good idea, newtover. I will try tomorrow; it's too late in Russia right now. Thank you!

Comment: Nizkiy poklon tebe, viruchil prosto super! Spasibo! Ne protiv esli ya tebya v LinkedIn dobavlu?