# multiple updation using single mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need to update multiple rows with different values.Is it possible to do in mysql?
ie,some thing like this

```
UPDATE landing_page SET (rotation_slot_begin='0',rotation_slot_end='0.333333333333' where landing_pageid=265),(rotation_slot_begin='0.333333333333',rotation_slot_end='0.666666666667' where landing_pageid=267),(rotation_slot_begin='0.666666666667',rotation_slot_end='1' where landing_pageid=268)
```

but this query is not working.I think something like this.Anybody can help me please

Comment: You cannot do it this way. This is not the purpose of the `UPDATE` statement. If you have to change different values for multiple rows, you have to use multiple statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579340/update-multiple-rows-with-known-keys-without-inserting-new-rows-if-nonexistent-ke/2580987#2580987) is the solution I have already posted before.

Answer (score 0):

An UPDATE query can only have one WHERE clause so you can't update multiple rows in that way.

See [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Comment: thanks.this documentation i already refered.if anybody know any other way to solve,then that may be helpful.thanks again

Comment: The link provided in the answer provided by @Lex seems useful. Maybe explaining the reason for trying to do this in one query might help with alternate ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use cases for this. Take a look at [this thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,276357,276529) for an example.

Personally, I would create and execute 3 seperate queries in this case.