# Is CASE practically useful for multiple UPDATEs in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, switch-statement, sql-update

It seems that the only way to use `UPDATE` for multiple rows is `CASE` as

```
UPDATE posts SET rates = CASE
WHEN post_id = '44' THEN rates + 'X'
WHEN post_id = '33' THEN rates + 'Y'
WHEN post_id = '73' THEN rates + 'Z'
WHEN post_id = '63' THEN rates + 'X'
...
ELSE rates END
```

Consider a table with 1 million rows. This needs to loop over 1 million records to update e.g. 10 rows.

If we use single UPDATE for each `UPDATE` as

```
UPDATE posts SET rates = rates + 'X' WHERE post_id='44'
UPDATE posts SET rates = rates + 'Y' WHERE post_id='33'
UPDATE posts SET rates = rates + 'Z' WHERE post_id='73'
UPDATE posts SET rates = rates + 'X' WHERE post_id='63'
...
```

we will have 10 queries, but we do not loop over 999,990 other rows.

Which is the most efficient methods when the number of `UPDATE`ing rows is significantly lesser than the total rows in the table?

**One More Question:** When we have `ELSE rates END` in the `CASE`; how mysql skips this record? Is a heavy task comparable with write?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579340/update-multiple-rows-with-known-keys-without-inserting-new-rows-if-nonexistent-k/2580987#2580987

Comment: Please do not sacrifice readability for tiny optimizations which are not necessarily faster. There is nothing wrong with sending multiple queries.

Comment: I also think this way; expensive method but very reliable!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of asking which is most efficient, why did you not experiment using the available tools, such as [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) or [profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profiles.html)?
Just add a where clause to your update -

```
UPDATE posts SET rates = CASE post_id
    WHEN 44 THEN rates + 'X'
    WHEN 33 THEN rates + 'Y'
    WHEN 73 THEN rates + 'Z'
    WHEN 63 THEN rates + 'X'
    ...
    END
WHERE post_id IN(44, 33, 73, 63...)
```

Comment: I performed my experiments, but what mysql EXPLAIN says does not guarantee the best performance in action. BUT your approach is absolutely brilliant! I think in this case `ELSE rates` is no longer needed. Then perfect!

Comment: Inline with @Guillaume's findings I have removed the else. I initially posted without the else but then had a crisis of confidence with regard to whether it was a valid statement.

Answer (score 4):

why don't you try:

```
UPDATE posts SET rates = rates + 'X' WHERE post_id in (44,33...)
```

?

To me, if you know the IDs of line to be updated, go straight to them.

If There is a limited number of different X, Y, Z, you can do this way too.

Do MySQL update a row if updated value is the same as before update ?

Comment: X represents an unknown value and varies from case to case!

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed an interesting question.
I made some tests, updating 10 rows in a 1 000 000 rows table.
Assuming post_id is the primary key:

- Method 1 (`CASE ... WHEN ...`) took **1.06s**
- Method 2 (10 queries) took **0.011s**
- Method 3 ([`JOIN` table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579340/update-multiple-rows-with-known-keys-without-inserting-new-rows-if-nonexistent-k/2580987#2580987), linked by @newtover) took **0.002s**
- Method 4 took **0.002s**

It is an average time based on 10 executions of each methods.

EDIT : And when updating 100 rows:

- Method 1: **3.232s**
- Method 2: **0.333s**
- Method 3: **0.032s**
- Method 4: **0.017s**

EDIT : Added [method 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9645551/263057) from @nnichols, without `ELSE` clause.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to test these different methods and posting your findings.

Comment: I wonder why Method 1 is so much slower for 100 rows as in both cases MySQL will need to scan through all rows anyway. The time spent for scanning all rows should be the predominant time waster, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, that surprised me too. I do not have an explanation though.

Comment: Did you try using the internal profiler to see where the time was being spent?  It seems strange that it should take that much longer to process the larger CASE expression.

Comment: very interesting benchmark! Thanks for this invaluable information. It seems that Method 4 is always winner.