# Update multiple rows at once?

Tags: mysql

I have an array:

```
[{id:1, sort:0}, {id:2, sort:1}]
```

This can potentially be  many id/sort pairs.

What's the best way to tackle an update on the sort column in mysql? I would rather not update each id at a time, is there something I can use?

Comment: something like this `UPDATE yourTableName SET sort = <desiredValue> WHERE <someConditionToIdentifyRowsToBeUpdated>`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579340/update-multiple-rows-with-known-keys-without-inserting-new-rows-if-nonexistent-k/2580987#2580987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the id is a unique key I would use an insert to do the job

```
INSERT INTO sometable(id, sort)
VALUES
(1,0),
(2,1),
......
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sort=VALUES(sort)
```

Comment: This will do an update if a record already exists. It tries to do an insert but with id being a unique key it will fail and trigger the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause to update the value of the sort column to the value that you are trying to insert into the sort column. Means that you can potentially update thousands of rows with a single SQL statement. The problem comes if id doesn't exist (in which case it will actually try and insert a record, and a fair chance it will fail if unspecified columns are defined as not null)